# make single page to be reasonable angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have html json data load on the view, and I want to make it like a book which has single page to be a reasonable amount of text for the screen size then the user will turn the page and see more. How do I make it happen.

controller.js

```
.controller('bookCtrl',function($scope,$sce){

                    $scope.book = bookinfo;

                //convert html function
                    $scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
                    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
                }
})

var bookinfo = [
{"content": "<body>\n<div class=\"pgmonospaced pgheader\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><br/>The Project Gutenberg EBook of A Study In Scarlet, by Arthur Conan Doyle<br/><br/>This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with<br/>almost no restrictions whatsoever.\u00a0 You may copy it, give it away or<br/>re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included<br/>with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org<br/><br/><br/>Title: A Study In Scarlet<br/><br/>Author: Arthur Conan Doyle<br/><br/>Release Date: July 12, 2008 [EBook #244]<br/>[Last updated: February 17, 2013]<br/><br/>Language: English<br/><br/><br/>*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK A STUDY IN SCARLET ***<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>}
]
```

index.html

```
    <div class="list card">     
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in book" >
            <h6 ng-bind-html="to_trusted(item.content)"></h6>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide your page content in number of pages. Iterate over that pages and show only one at a time and on click of next/previous button show next/previous page using `ng-if/ng-show` directives.

Also you can use `angular-ui` for pagination